# Calling setState in Flutter TabBar onTap not working

Tags: flutter

See the attached sample code. If I clear the state when changing tabs by using TabBar onTap, the updated state is not reflected in the TabBarViews.

In my sample code, clicking on the buttons in the TabBarViews sets state which highlights the button. When changing tabs, the buttons in the tabs should no longer be highlighted, but they still are.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabBarDemo> createState() => _TabBarDemoState();
}

class _TabBarDemoState extends State<TabBarDemo> {
  int state = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: const [
                Tab(text: 'One'),
                Tab(text: 'Two'),
              ],
              onTap: (value) {
                setState(() => state = 0);
              },
            ),
            title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: (state == 1) ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() => state = 1);
                  },
                  child: const Text('One'),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: (state == 2) ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() => state = 2);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Two'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: HI, are you trying to achieve that each button should have its own state? so each one is nor related to the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this was an issue that has been recently fixed by the flutter team. You can have a look at it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/107651).

If you will copy your code to dartpad but use the master channel instead of stable, you will notice that it works as expected. You can try it [here](https://dartpad.dev/?channel=master)

I presume the flutter team will merge this into the next stable release.

In your IDE terminal you can use this:

`flutter channel master`

and then

`flutter run`

Alternatively, if you want to run the stable channel you could make use of [Provider](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for state management.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info, will anxiously await the next release!

Answer (score 0):

SetState is not needed here infact stateless widget can do that task. Have a look here and in the body try to implement like this only. I have attached an image for you[image]

Comment: You didn't understand what he said !!